# reference error when I try to get a value from other slice redux toolkit?

Tags: redux-toolkit

I am trying to import a value form other slice that has some user information, any idea why I am getting this nasty error ? I read it is normal to request data from other slices, the error seem to be like the slice cannot find the store... below is my code structure, my store is at the top of my app, does this getState function works in a component only and not in slice to other slice .

```js
import React from 'react';
import ReactDOM from 'react-dom';
import { HashRouter } from 'react-router-dom';
import App from './App';
import './index.css';
// Redux Tool Kit
import { store } from './app/store';
import { Provider } from 'react-redux';

ReactDOM.render(
  <React.StrictMode>
    <Provider store={store}>
      <App />
    </Provider>
  </React.StrictMode>,
  document.getElementById('root')
);
```

```js
import {
  RootState,
  store
} from './store';
import {
  createSlice,
  PayloadAction
} from '@reduxjs/toolkit';


export interface miscState {
  dayNumber: true,
  dayOfWeek: false,
};

export const miscSlice = createSlice({
  name: 'misc',
  initialState,
  reducers: {

    setDisplayDay: (state, action: PayloadAction < {
      bool: boolean;type: string
    } > ) => {
      const {
        user,
        uid
      } = store.getState().global.currentUser;
      const setDisplay = async() => {
        const docRef = doc(db, colDynamic(user)[0], uid);
        await updateDoc(docRef, {
          [action.payload.type]: action.payload.bool,
        });
      };
    },
  },
});

// Values
export const MiscCurrentState = (state: RootState) => state.misc;
// Action creators are generated for each case reducer function
export const {
  setDisplayDay
} = miscSlice.actions;

export default miscSlice.reducer;
```

```js
import { configureStore } from '@reduxjs/toolkit';
// Global
import globalReducer from './globalSlice';
// Misc
import miscReducer from './miscSlice';

export const store = configureStore({
  reducer: {
    global: globalReducer,
    misc: miscReducer,
  },
});

// Infer the `RootState` and `AppDispatch` types from the store itself
export type RootState = ReturnType<typeof store.getState>;
// Inferred type: {posts: PostsState, comments: CommentsState, users: UsersState}
export type AppDispatch = typeof store.dispatch;
```

[image]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In Redux, you are not allowed to access the store from within a reducer. A reducer has to be a pure function that only reads the variables passed into it - so all information you have is the slice's own `state` and the `action` being dispatched. You are not allowed to read a global variable, have any kind of side effect or read from the global Redux store to get the data of another slice.

Comment: I would recommend just asking in the redux channel on Reactiflux - there are lots of people there to help. I'll chime in in case I'm around and have the time but no guarantees.